# Bash script to create txt file silently

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, cron

I have a created a bash script on a headless ubuntu server that is changing some settings depending on other criteria. The script works fine, but I want to run this with cron once a day and at the moment I store the current settings in a text file so the script knows what settings are currently being used before sequentially changing to the next settings.

The problem I have is that I seem to have a permission denied error?!! The script is owned by root:root and the folder has read/write permissions for the user (clearly).

I currently create the file (successfully) with the following command:

`echo ${fileNames[$arrayUsed]} | sudo tee /usr/current-conf.txt`

If I remove 'sudo' then the file creation gives me a permission denied error. This is true for `awk` as well as

`echo ${fileNames[$arrayUsed]} > /usr/current-conf.txt`

Ideally I would like for this file creation to happen silently (without echo) but none of the solutions I have found work.

Additionally, I would value the right way to add this script to cron (although I can look this up if prefer to answer 1 question at a time...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried creating the cron job with `sudo crontab -e` so it is a root cron?

Comment: Thanks @Terrance, I haven't actually tried anything with cron as yet as I wanted to get the script working first (which it is apart from this issue). Actually, you might tell me that by having a text echo of my settings does nothing and therefore should not be an error. But I recall somewhere reading that by not sending text to 'null' or equivalent that this creates a memory leak? But perhaps not if I am sending to a configuration text file? You can tell I am very much a noob...

Comment: The /usr folder is owned by root so it will not be writeable by a regular user.  The regular user has full write capabilities into their own home folder by default.  Any other folder would require root or sudo permissions.

Comment: A script would need execute permission for the user (or root), in addition to read/write. Looks like this script needs to run as root (not a user), since you want to install files into /usr.

Comment: So if a script is owned by root does it not automatically run as root?

Comment: Ownership of the file means who owns and runs it, not how it runs.  If you tried to run a script owned by root you would probably get a permission denied.  That's why there is `sudo`.  Think of `sudo` as "Super User DO".  `sudo` basically gives you root to run.  A script owned by you with permissions of `rwx------` can only be read, write and executed by you.  Permissions are in 3 groups `rwxrwxrwx`  The first 3 `rwx` is for the (u)ser or owner.  Then next 3 are for the (g)roup.  And the last 3 is for all (o)thers.  https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/

Comment: Thank you @Terrance (and @user535733) that is all very helpful! Can I ask perhaps another simple question... but when I SSH into the server with Putty and run the script (./) then to create the file each time I get an 'echo' of the text going into the file. If I run the script using cron then what happens to the 'echo' text?